# CakePHP fav icon

Tags: php, cakephp, favicon

How can the default fav icon be changed in [CakePHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CakePHP)?

Answer (score 21):

Simply replace the file `app/webroot/favicon.ico` with your own version.

Comment: I changed it with another image.Still it shows the default image.

Comment: It is probably cached by your browser. Clearing the cache should fix the issue.

Comment: @screenavc - Simply point your browser to http://localhost/path/to/cakeapp/favicon.ico and hit refresh. Should do the trick! However, Firefox's favicon caching can be a pain sometimes.

Answer (score 4):

Use `Html Helper`, put it in `<head>` tag:
 (File `/app/View/Layouts/default.ctp`)

```
echo $this->Html->meta ( 'favicon.ico', '/favicon.ico', array (
    'type' => 'icon' 
) );
```

You also use hyperlink, for example, I used StackOver Flow's favicon:

```
echo $this->Html->meta ( 'favicon.ico', 'http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico?v=038622610830', array (
    'type' => 'icon' 
) );
```

Of course, You maybe put favicon five in another folder in your web resources folder. For example: put favicon.ico in `/app/webroot/img/decor/favicon.ico` :

```
echo $this->Html->meta ( 'favicon.ico', '/img/decor/favicon.ico', array (
    'type' => 'icon' 
) );
```

More information: "favicon.ico" is the convention. Don't chage file name.
Create or choose a favicon: http://www.favicon.cc/ Or see HTML source (Ctrl + U) from another website, and copy & paste.

Work with CakePHP lastest version (2.6.0). Reference: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#inserting-well-formatted-elements

Comment: This works in Firefox and in Microsoft Edge, but for some peculiar reason, it does **not** work in **Google Chrome**. The only thing that seems to work for Chrome is putting the favicon.ico file in the very top-most document-root directory, which kind of ruins any possibility of having different icons for different sub-directories.

Answer (score 3):

Simply replace the favicon inside app/webroot with your own *.ico favicon. 
And you're done ! 
If your favicon won't show after you done as above, Re-refresh your browser Or, simply clear web history.

Comment: This also does not work for Google Chrome. I haven't tried it in the other browsers.

Answer (score 2):

Given like this

```
 <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="<?php echo $this->webroot; ?>img/bullet.jpg">
```

In this way I  got the favicon.In that case no need to rename the default favicon.ico

Answer (score 1):

In your webroot folder change `cake.icon.png` image instead of your image.

In your `view\layouts\default.ctp` just add this code

```
echo $this->Html->meta('icon');
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you need to delete the default favicon.ico icon file from webroot directory and place your own picture. But make sure you convert that picture in icon format and rename it to favicon. I think it should work because it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had to put the icon into the /img/ folder - it just wouldn't accept it in the root folder.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this for displaying favicon icon.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="<?php echo FULL_BASE_PATH; ?>/favicon.ico" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
    echo $this->Html->meta('favicon.ico','/favicon.ico', array('type' => 'icon'));     
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your favicon with app/webroot/favicon.ico and wait for sometime, as it require some time to reflect on browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Check your layout.ctp file to check if your favicon is located at the right place.

Put this in your header

```
<?php echo $this->Html->meta(
    'favicon.ico',
    '/favicon.ico',
    array('type' => 'icon')
);
?>
```

The size to use is 16x16, png renamed in .ico

Answer (score -1):

set the following snippet in your layout:

Html->meta('favicon.png','img/favicon.png',array('type' => 'icon')); ?>
// favicon.png is your image in webroot/img

Comment: Though we thank you for your answer, it would be better if it provided additional value on top of the other answers. In this case, your answer does not provide additional value, since another user already posted that solution. If a previous answer was helpful to you, you should vote it up instead of repeating the same information.